# How to stretch full height of a div using CSS?

Tags: html, css

How to stretch full height of a div using CSS?

I'm trying to stretch a div 100%. Applied `min-height: 100%;` but no result.

```
<div class="mydiv"></div>
.mydiv {
min-height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: First, is your div displayed in `inline` mode? Second, does the parent element of your div has a specific height?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your css, try add this, it work for me :)

```
.divName{ 
    width: 100%; 
    height: 100%; 
    position: fixed; 
    top: 0; 
    left: 0;
    background:red;
 }
```

Comment: Thanks , Working fine :)

Comment: my pleasure, thumbs up hehe